# Выбор патерна для обработки платежа

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Добрый день! Пишу на Java. Есть следующая логика: полная цепочка проведения платежа следующая:

1. проверка
2. оплата (берутся данные из п.1)
3. проверка статуса (берутся данные из п.2)
4. отмена (опционально).

От поставщика услуг могут быть следующие ошибки:

- обрыв соединения на этапе 1-2
- зависание платежа в статусе "Обработка" на 10-20 мин...

В случае обрыва на этапе 1, нужны попытки повтора запроса.
В случае обрыва на этапе 2, опрашивать статус около 20 мин.
+ Валидация ответов, полученных  в случае успешных ответов.

Подскажите, как лучше организовать код, на какие паттерны обратить
   внимание?

Comment: познавшие дзен разработчики это не те, которые знают где и какой паттерн применить, а те которые знают где можно обойтись и без них

Comment: Архитектор уволился? Так-то, за ответы на подобные вопросы деньги платят =)

Answer (score 1):

Напрашивается паттерн "Цепочка обязанностей"